# d3.js x3dom: How to freeze camera position and get an axis?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, x3dom

I saw the [3d bar chart](http://bl.ocks.org/camio/5087116) example of d3 and another [3d example](https://gist.github.com/ZJONSSON/1291667), and the one thing I wanted to do was to be able to have a static camera position. Tried the viewpoint fieldOfView, but it just doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help with having a camera at a fixed position? I don't want the user to be able to rotate the 3d scene.

Also, I couldn't figure out how they displayed the x, y and x axes on the screen. Is there a tutorial or an API reference with which I can figure out how to use x3dom in d3.js? I want to know what the commands and syntax are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

x3dom doesn't have option to disable rotation. But you can add modify their source code to do it. I did this for one of my projects:

```
// add disableRotation option
var validParams = array_to_object([
  // ...
  'disableRotation',
  // ...
]);

// disable rotation onDrag
x3dom.Viewarea.prototype.onDrag = function (x, y, buttonState) {
  // ...
  if (this._doc.properties.getProperty('disableRotation', 'false') === 'true' && buttonState === 1) {
    return;
  }
}

// append this to your x3d tag
x3d.append("param")
   .attr("name", "disableRotation")
   .attr("value", "false");
```

See this example for how to draw axes on screen:

http://bl.ocks.org/hlvoorhees/5986172

Comment: Thanks. I had a look at the API earlier, but it wasn't very intuitive. Wish there were better explanations in the x3dom documentation.

Comment: Hey! This is so cool! I thought you meant I should take the actual x3dom source code from github and modify it. But on pasting this code in my bar chart code, the camera got fixed. Wonderful! Thanks a lot man!